# Recoger los ID para JavaScript error

Tags: php, javascript, laravel, laravel-5

Tegno esta formula en JavaScript:

```
  function formula() {
var cantidad = document.form1.cantidad.value;
var precio_unitario = document.form1.precio_unitario.value;
var total = document.form1.total.value;


try{

cantidad = (isNaN(parseInt(cantidad)))? 0 : parseInt(cantidad);
precio_unitario = (isNaN(parseInt(precio_unitario)))? 0 : parseInt(precio_unitario);
total = (isNaN(parseInt(total)))? 0 : parseInt(total);



var uni_iva =  (cantidad*precio_unitario);
document.form1.total.value =  uni_iva;

}
catch(e) {}
}
```

Que debe de Recoger datos de un formulario en Laravel y tal como este:

```
    {!! Form::open(['route' => 'puos.store', 'method' => 'POST']) !!}
<div id="form1" class="form-group">

    <div  style="float:left; width:49%;">

        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('puo', 'PUO') !!}
            {!! Form::text('puo', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Número de la PUO']) !!}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('id_empresa', 'Empresa') !!}
            {!! Form::select('id_empresa', $id_empresa, null, ['class' => 'form-control input-sm', 'placeholder' => 'Seleccione una opcion']) !!}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('id_proyecto', 'Proyectos') !!}
            {!! Form::select('id_proyecto', $id_proyecto, null, ['class' => 'form-control input-sm', 'placeholder' => 'Seleccione una opcion']) !!}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('partida', 'Partida') !!}
            {!! Form::text('partida', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Partidad realizada por:']) !!}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('forma_pago', 'Forma de Pago') !!}
            {!! Form::text('forma_pago', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Código del Ticket', 'required']) !!}
        </div> 

        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('id_empleado_solicitante', 'Solicitante') !!}
            {!! Form::select('id_empleado_solicitante', $id_empleado_solicitante, null, ['class' => 'form-control input-sm', 'placeholder' => 'Seleccione una opcion']) !!}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('id_empleado_aprueba', 'Aprobado por:') !!}
            {!! Form::select('id_empleado_aprueba', $id_empleado_aprueba, null, ['class' => 'form-control input-sm', 'placeholder' => 'Seleccione una opcion']) !!}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('id_producto', 'Producto') !!}
            {!! Form::select('id_producto', $id_producto, null, ['class' => 'form-control input-sm', 'placeholder' => 'Seleccione una opcion']) !!}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('cantidad', 'Cantidad') !!}
            {!! Form::text('cantidad', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Cantidad obtenida', 'required', 'onKeyUp' => 'formula()', 'id' => 'cantidad']) !!}
        </div>

        <div>
            {!! Form::submit('Registrar', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) !!}
        </div>             
    </div>

    <div  style="float:right; width:49%;">
        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('precio_unitario', 'Precio Unitario') !!}
            {!! Form::text('precio_unitario', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Precio por unidad' , 'required', 'onKeyUp' => 'formula()', 'id' => 'precio_unitario']) !!}
        </div> 

        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('descuento_porcentaje', 'Descuento (%)') !!}
            {!! Form::text('descuento_porcentaje', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Descuento %' , 'required']) !!}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('iva', 'IVA') !!}
            {!! Form::text('iva', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'IVA' , 'required']) !!}
        </div> 

        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('precio_total', 'Precio Total') !!}
            {!! Form::text('precio_total', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Precio Total' , 'required']) !!}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('descuento', 'Descuento') !!}
            {!! Form::text('descuento', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Descuento' , 'required']) !!}
        </div> 

        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('preciounitario_descuento', 'Precio Unitario Descuento') !!}
            {!! Form::text('preciounitario_descuento', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Precio Unitario Descuento' , 'required']) !!}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('iva_total', 'IVA Total') !!}
            {!! Form::text('iva_total', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'IVA Total' , 'required']) !!}
        </div> 

        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('total', 'Total de la Factura') !!}
            {!! Form::text('total', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Total' , 'required', 'id' => 'total']) !!}
        </div>  

        <div class="form-group">
                {!! Form::label('id_proveedor', 'Proveedor') !!}
                {!! Form::select('id_proveedor', $id_proveedor, null, ['class' => 'form-control input-sm', 'placeholder' => 'Seleccione una opcion']) !!}
        </div>                                      
    </div>   
</div> 
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Pero creo que la `ID` `form1` esta dando error y no lo estoy llamando bien diria yo

Comment: Tener un catch vacío es una muy mala práctica: mira si se captura un error y cuál es: `console.log(e)`

Comment: `TypeError: document.form1 is undefined`. Si le pogno el `ID` al `form` lanza el mismo error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Debia de colocar un `name` en el `form` denominado `form1` entonces `JavaScript` ya recoge los datos y los escribe en el campo

```
 {!! Form::open(['route' => 'puos.store', 'method' => 'POST', 'id' => 'form1','name' => 'form1']) !!}
```